# pg_recvlogical: could not clear search_path: ERROR: syntax error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.6

What could be causing this error?

```sh
$ pg_recvlogical --slot test --create-slot -d postgres \
                 -h 1.2.3.4 -p 5432 -U myUser

pg_recvlogical: could not clear search_path: ERROR:  syntax error
```

Comment: I cannot find that error message in the PostgreSQL source. Is this standard PostgreSQL? Which of the versions you tagged?

Comment: I just began receiving this message as well with 9.5.12 from the PGDG Debian/Ubuntu repos.

Comment: http://www.postgresql-archive.org/BUG-15116-pg-recvlogical-always-fails-td6011409.html